# DAL, BLL, Facade. Old model?

Tags: c#, architecture

Many Java programmers joke, which all use model DAL, BLL and Facade when programming in C#. I wonder, those who program the more time that I C # if this model is recommended, or if this model is outdated.

I've worked with this model, and frankly did not like because it is very cumbersome to change all layers always. Would like to know your opinions.

Comment: @David_001 No, it would be a layer before the interface. own to access web services. Should she use a webservice future (point of call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to implement the Domain Driven Design method of using Services, Repositories and entities. I have found this pattern really flexible when used with DI and I prefer it to using a DAL/BLL. Maybe research it to see what you think?

Comment: I will search. Thanks for the suggestion @Matt